# dropdownlist value into asp:label

Tags: c#

I have

```
public class ListA
{

   private string code;
   private string name;

   public string Code { get { return code; } set { code = value; } }
   public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

}
```

I am populating the dropdownlist with code:name.

and I have an asp:label in which I want to show only Name that is selected in the dropdownlist.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your DropDownList `DataValueField = "Name"`

and then use `myLabel.Text = myDropDownList.SelectedValue;`

Comment: I want code and name in dropdownlist. Both are required. But in label only name is needed

Comment: @bubblygirl-0515: Yup, I answered your other question. Using my answer, you can still set the DataValueVield to just Name. It won't change what is displayed to the user.

Comment: Yuriy, can I get your email id. I need one more help and that's a bit compliacted to type and I cannot post the code on web.

Comment: @bubblygirl-0515: You can send email here M8R-fn1jb2@mailinator.com. Although I'd still suggest against sending anything secret or proprietary. I am a stranger on the web, and have no incentive to see either.

Answer (score 2):

You will essentially need to create a function/method for handling the OnChange or OnSelectedIndexChange event for your dropdown.  When the event is fired, your code should set the Text property of the label based upon the Text of your SelectedItem in the dropdown.

You could do this entirely in JavaScript, but this is a sample of how this can be done purely in the code behind...  You could also look at integrating either UpdatePanels or some other form to make these changes asynchronously.

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MyDropDown.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        MyLabel.Text = MyDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

**FRONT END**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Test1">Test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Test3">Test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This will not work because the Text is displaying a special value, based on her previous question.

Comment: Previous question?  "I have an asp:label in which I want to show only Name that is selected in the dropdownlist.  How can I do that?"  This answer does indeed take care of the question...

Answer (score 0):

if on a postback:

```
myLabel.Text = myDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

if you want it to change immediately in the browser, when the user selects something different, you'll have to use javascript, such as this:

JavaScript:

```
function updateText(ddl, lblId) {
    var lbl = document.getElementById(lblId);
    lbl.innerHTML = ddl[ddl.SelectedIndex].value;
}
```

.NET:

```
myDropDownList.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateText(this, '" + myLabel.ClientID + "');");
```

**EDIT**
Completely besides the point, but since I see you're not using them: have you heard of auto properties? Since C#3.5, you can write that exact class using just the following code:

```
public class ListA
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subroutine that handles the OnSelectedIndexChanged event. Capture the selected value and set it to the text value of your label.